# Errorhandling using PowerShell 7 and Windows PowerShell Compatibility

Tags: windows, powershell

Recently I've started transitioning to using PowerShell 7 for my scripting needs, since most of my required modules are now compatible.

However the "[MSOnline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msonline/)" module has not yet been updated, and they recommend using the `-UseWindowsPowerShell` parameter when importing the module.

This is absolutely great, and the module can be used to (almost) it's full potential.
However the `-ErrorVariable` parameter does not seem to work, and I'm therefore unable to do any error handling.

See below code for an example of what doesn't work:

```
Import-Module MSOnline -UseWindowsPowerShell
Connect-MsolService -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable msolError
Write-Host $msolError
```

It seems that the `-ErrorAction` parameter is respected, but I can't seem to get anything inside the error variable.

**Does anyone know if it is possible to somehow get the error values of a module loaded like this?**

Comment: What happens if you try to output `$Error[0]`?

Comment: It's empty unfortunately

Comment: Does the cmdlet throw an error if you don't include an `-ErrorAction` parameter? Is `Connect-MSOLService` in fact failing?

Comment: When not specifying an ErrorAction the error output is printed to the console.
However I've tried setting it as a variable `$output = Get-MsolService` and printing it like that but there is no output.

Answer (score 0):

`-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` will supress any error messages. Remove it from the command to get an output.

Command should be:
`Connect-MsolService -ErrorVariable "msolError"`

The just call $msolError to view the error.

Comment: That's not true. `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` supresses error messages from being displayed, but does not prevent `-ErrorVariable` from being populated.

The example does not work either, as the Error Message simply get's output and the variable is not populated.